# Loop Through Sections in PowerPoint with C#

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I try to Loop through the sections in Powerpoint using C#.

first I want to check the property ActivePresentation.HasSection, but get an error.
Then the ActivePresentation.SectionCount also shows an error - also the ActivePresentation.SectionProperties.Count

my code:

```
if(oPresentation.HasSections == true)
{
                for (int iSection = oPresentation.SectionCount; iSection >0; iSection--)
                {
                    oPresentation.SectionProperties.Delete(iSection, false);
                }
            }
```

I can create section using C# with

```
oPresentation.SectionProperties.AddBeforeSlide(1, false)
```

I can delete a section using c# with

```
oPresentation.SectionProperties.Delete(2, false)
```

But does anybody knows how to Loop through the sections in PowerPoint by C# and Delete them all? How to check if a presentation has sections?

In VBA this is not a Problem:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/PowerPoint-2010-Insert-b6f1e012

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: oPresentation.HasSections raises
error CS1061: 'Presentation' does not contain a definition for 'HasSections' and no extension method 'HasSections' accepting a first argument of type 'Presentation' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 

oPresentation.SectionProperties.Count raises
error CS0428: Cannot convert method group 'Count' to non-delegate type 'object'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

Comment: blaze_125: it is not about the index, even in debugger mode the oPresentation.SectionCount or oPresentation.SectionProperties.Count raises the above Errors - they return just the exception.

Answer (score 1):

For all who are looking the same, I got it working myself. I think there is no direct Access to the oPresentation.SectionProperties.Count - after using the variable it worked. Maybe someone could explain me that, I'm new in this C#.

```
        PowerPoint.SectionProperties oSections = oPresentation.SectionProperties;

            if(oSections.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int iSection = oSections.Count; iSection > 0; iSection--)
                {
                    oSections.Delete(iSection, false);
                }
            }
```